# Is there a default function I could use for comparisons with React.memo?

Tags: reactjs, object, comparison, memo

I have a `<Track/>` component that have an object as prop; like

```
const myData = {
   "location"      : ["http://example.com/1.ogg", "http://example.com/2.mp3"],
   "identifier"    : ["http://example.com/1/", "http://example.com/2/"],
   "title"         : "Track title",
   "creator"       : "Artist name",
   "annotation"    : "Some text",
   "info"          : "http://example.com/",
   "image"         : "http://example.com/",
   "album"         : "Album name",
   "trackNum"      : 1,
   "duration"      : 0,
   "link"          : [
     {"http://example.com/rel/1/" : "http://example.com/body/1/"},
     {"http://example.com/rel/2/" : "http://example.com/body/2/"}
   ],
   "meta"          : [
     {"http://example.com/rel/1/" : "my meta 14"},
     {"http://example.com/rel/2/" : "345"}
   ],
   "extension"     : {
     "http://example.com/app/1/" : [ARBITRARY_EXTENSION_BODY, ARBITRARY_EXTENSION_BODY],
     "http://example.com/app/2/" : [ARBITRARY_EXTENSION_BODY]
   }
 }
```

Used in

```
<Track track={myData} onClick={handleClick}/>
```

When I update `myData`, I create a new object, which makes React re-render my component, even if its props have equal values.

I've looked at `React.memo`, which could help to avoid re-rendering with a custom function, like

```
export default React.memo(Track,isEqualTrack);
```

Where I would `JSON.stringify()` to check my data for equality :

```
function isEqualProp(key,prev,next){
  switch(key){
    case 'track':
      return (JSON.stringify(prev)===JSON.stringify(next))
    break;
  }
}

function isEqualTrack(prevTrackProps, nextTrackProps) {

  const props = Object.keys(nextTrackProps);

  //find the first prop that has changed
  const changedProp = props.find(function(prop){
    const prevValue = prevTrackProps[prop];
    const nextValue = nextTrackProps[prop];
    return !isEqualProp(prop,prevValue,nextValue);
  })

  if (changedProp){
    return false;
  }

  return true;

}
```

But I would need a default function to compare the props I don't want a special check on.

```
function isEqualProp(key,prev,next){
  switch(key){
    case 'track':
      return (JSON.stringify(prev)===JSON.stringify(next))
    break;
    default:
      //I NEED A DEFAULT FUNCTION HERE
  }
}
```

Does that exists ?
Or do you have another solution to not re-render my component ?
As you see, the data is nested so I can't split it into several "simple" props.

Thanjs a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

From https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

> This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.

You should use useMemo to avoid creating a new reference for your `myData` object instead. That way react's built in shallow comparison would be enough